# How to render the payment method in custom layout file checkoutnew_index_index?

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout

I'm trying to create a new checkout layout with shipping address, shipping methods and payment in single page.
Though I use the following code snippet inside the shipping-step section,

```
<item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
<item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_CheckoutNew/js/view/payment</item>
<item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">payment-options</item>
<item name="children" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="renders" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
            <!-- merge payment method renders here -->
        </item>
    </item>
    <item name="additional-payment-validators" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
            <!-- merge payment validators here -->
            <item name="email-validator" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/email-validator</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </item>
    <item name="customer-email" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/form/element/email</item>
        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">customer-email</item>
        <item name="tooltip" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="description" xsi:type="string" translate="true">We'll send your order confirmation here.</item>
        </item>
        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="before-login-form" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">before-login-form</item>
                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                    <!-- before login form fields -->
                </item>
            </item>
            <item name="additional-login-form-fields" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">additional-login-form-fields</item>
                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                    <!-- additional login form fields -->
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </item>
    <item name="beforeMethods" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">beforeMethods</item>
        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
            <!-- merge additional data before payment methods here -->
        </item>
        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="validate-select" xsi:type="string">true</item>
        </item>
        <!-- Value of region_id field is filtered by the value of county_id attribute -->
        <item name="filterBy" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="target" xsi:type="string">${ $.provider }:${ $.parentScope }.country_id</item>
            <item name="field" xsi:type="string">country_id</item>
        </item>
    </item>
    <item name="payments-list" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_CheckoutNew/js/view/payment/list</item>
        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">payment-methods-list</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="0" xsi:type="string">checkout.steps.shipping-step.shippingAddress.payment.renders</item>
                <item name="1" xsi:type="string">checkout.steps.shipping-step.shippingAddress.payment.additional-payment-validators</item>
            </item>
        </item>
        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="before-place-order" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">before-place-order</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">before-place-order</item>
                <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/payment/before-place-order</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </item>
    <!-- merge your payment methods here -->
    <item name="afterMethods" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">afterMethods</item>
        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
            <!-- merge additional data after payment methods here -->
        </item>
    </item>
</item>
```

then called payment in shipping.html

```
<!-- ko foreach: getRegion('payment-options') -->
<!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
<!--/ko-->
```

But the payment methods not appear.
Any body having idea what i'm missing here?

Answer (score 1):

After digging long time found the cause of this problem. We would need to provide the payment method details in the renders section of the custom layout xml.

```
<referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="renders" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <!-- merge payment method renders here -->
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="offline-payments" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_OfflinePayments/js/view/payment/offline-payments</item>
                                                                <item name="methods" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="checkmo" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="isBillingAddressRequired" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                    <item name="banktransfer" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="isBillingAddressRequired" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                    <item name="cashondelivery" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="isBillingAddressRequired" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                    <item name="purchaseorder" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="isBillingAddressRequired" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
```

In my case, I have to provide the this details in checkoutnew_index_index.xml